# Merging two worksheets and removing rows that do not match based on values in columns - Originpro

Tags: time, merge, reduce, originlab

How can I delete rows in columns A,B,C,D,E,F,G in Worksheet 1 if the values in column A of Worksheet 1 do not match with values in column A in Worksheet 2 in OriginPro2024 (Academic). There is no other data in Worksheet 2 other that the data in Column A. The data i want to match with is time in days. Worksheet 1 is called "1" and Worksheet 2 is called "2". I have  154278 rows in Worksheet 1 and 95499 rows in Worksheet 2 and I want to reduce to 95499 rows in Worksheet 1.

I tried using "Restructure" function in Origin using Join Two sheets by Columns but this did not work